# Como posso criar um método customizado no model do Laravel e combinar com o resultado de outro?

Tags: php, laravel

Estou trabalhando com o Laravel e criei o seguinte método para fazer pesquisa em um model:

```
public function search($string)
{
    return (strlen($string) > 0) ? $this->where('name', 'like', '%' . $string . '%') : $this;
}
```

Eu utilizo ele da seguinte maneira:

```
$this->clientMain->search('teste');
```

Assim ele me retorna o resultado que eu quero como uma Builder ou o próprio objeto, desta forma eu consigo pegar o retorno e criar outros filtros como por exemplo:

```
$this->clientMain->search('teste')->where('status_id', 3);
```

Ate ai tudo bem, então eu criei outro método para me ajudar nos filtros:

```
public function realActive()
{
    return $this->where('status_id', 1)->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where(function ($query) {
            $query->whereHas('Responsible', function ($query){
                $query->where('active', 1);
            });
        })->orWhere(function ($query) {
            $fields = ['name', 'birthday', 'cpf', 'zip_code', 'neighborhood', 'street', 'number'];
            $entities = ['sex_id', 'city_id'];
            $query = $this->removeFilled($fields, $query);
            $query = $this->removeEmptyEntity($entities, $query);
            $query->where(function ($query){
                $contacts = ['telephone', 'cellphone', 'whatsapp'];
                $this->checkContact($contacts, $query);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Onde eu o utilizo de uma forma bem parecida com o search:

```
$this->clientMain->realActive();
```

Ele me retorna uma Builder também, e da mesma forma ele me retorna o que eu quero, assim como acontece com o search, eu também consigo fazer algo como:

```
$this->clientMain->realActive()->where('status_id', 3);
```

O meu problema é o seguinte, eu queria combinar os dois desta forma:

```
$clientsMain = $this->clientMain->search('teste')->realActive();
```

Ou seja pegando o resultado da pesquisa e filtrar os "Reais Ativos", mas quando eu faço isso eu recebo o seguinte erro:

> "Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::realActive does not exist."

Porque ele me retornou uma Builder e a Builder não tem o método realActive.

Eu fiz uma 'gambiarra' que funcionou, no meu método realActive eu fiz desta forma:

```
public function realActive($builder = null)
{
    if(is_null($builder)){
        $builder = $this;
    }
    return $builder->where('status_id', 1)->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where(function ($query) {
            $query->whereHas('Responsible', function ($query){
                $query->where('active', 1);
            });
        })->orWhere(function ($query) {
            $fields = ['name', 'birthday', 'cpf', 'zip_code', 'neighborhood', 'street', 'number'];
            $entities = ['sex_id', 'city_id'];
            $query = $this->removeFilled($fields, $query);
            $query = $this->removeEmptyEntity($entities, $query);
            $query->where(function ($query){
                $contacts = ['telephone', 'cellphone', 'whatsapp'];
                $this->checkContact($contacts, $query);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

E na hora de utilizar eu faço o seguinte:

```
$clientsMain = $this->clientMain->search('teste');
$clientsMain = $this->clientMain->realActive($clientsMain);
```

Funciona, mas eu queria saber se existe uma forma de fazer assim:

```
$clientsMain = $this->clientMain->search('teste')->realActive();
```

Além de ser mais pratico, é mais fácil de ler, e acredito ser possível já que eu posso fazer no Laravel algo como:

```
$clientsMain = $this->clientMain->where('name', 'teste')->where('last_name', 'outro teste');
```

Como posso criar um método customizado no model do Laravel e combinar com o resultado de outro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que a função `where()` não retorna a própria classe, retorna uma instância do `QueryBuilder`.

A função `search()` tem o seguinte retorno:

```
return $this->where(...);
```

Então, não está mais retornando uma instância da classe `clientMain`, porém uma instância da classe `QueryBuilder`.

Ok, como resolver isso?

O Laravel possui uma funcionalidade chamada [`Local Scopes`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#local-scopes)(dê uma lida), que te permite alterar a `$query` atual e retorná-la já filtrada. Existe também a possibilidade de usar escopos com parâmetros, nesse caso o primeiro parâmetro deve ser sempre a `$query`, e em seguida os demais.

Alterando suas funções  para usar os escopos, ficaria assim:

```
/**
 * Coloque uma descrição topzera desse escopo
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query
 * @param string $str
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
public function scopeSearch($query, $str)
{
    return $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $str . '%');
}


/**
 * Aqui também
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
public function scopeRealActive($query)
{
    return $query->where('status_id', 1)->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where(function ($query) {
            $query->whereHas('Responsible', function ($query){
                $query->where('active', 1);
            });
        })->orWhere(function ($query) {
            $fields = ['name', 'birthday', 'cpf', 'zip_code', 'neighborhood', 'street', 'number'];
            $entities = ['sex_id', 'city_id'];
            $query = $this->removeFilled($fields, $query);
            $query = $this->removeEmptyEntity($entities, $query);
            $query->where(function ($query){
                $contacts = ['telephone', 'cellphone', 'whatsapp'];
                $this->checkContact($contacts, $query);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Daí, você vai conseguir usar da forma que você queria:

```
$clientsMain = $this->clientMain->search('teste')->realActive();
```

Ou, julgando que sua classe se chame `Client`, assim:

```
$clients = Client::search('teste')->realActive();
```

Comment: Muito bom, funcionou perfeitamente!